# Is File::Spec really necessary?

Tags: perl

I know all about the history of different OSes having different path formats, but at this point in time there seems to be a general agreement (with one sorta irrelevant holdout*) about how paths work.  I find the whole `File::Spec` route of path management to be clunky and a useless pain.

Is it really worth having this baroque set of functions to manipulate paths?  Please convince me I am being shortsighted.

* Irrelevant because even MS Windows allows forward slashes in paths, which means the only funky thing is the volume at the start and that has never really been a problem for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two major systems have volumes. What's the parent of C:? In unix, it's `C:/..`. In Windows, it's `C:..`. (Unfortunately, most people misuse File::Spec to the point of breaking this.)

There are three different set of path separators in the major systems. The fact that Windows supports "/" could simplify building paths, but it doesn't help in parsing them or to canonising them.

File::Spec also provides useful functions that make it useful even if every system did use the same style of paths, such as the one that turns a path into a relative path.

That said, I never use File::Spec. I use [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path::Class) instead. Without sacrificing any usability or usefulness, Path::Class provides a much better interface. And it doesn't let users mishandle volumes.

Comment: What other major system has volumes?

Comment: @Chas. Owens, looks like it doesn't use "/" or ".." either (unless in unix compatibility mode)

Comment: Is VMS really a viable platform? I thought Perl support for it was more out of habit and kindness towards the few people still stuck on it. If you consider VMS a viable platform, then `File::Spec` or other path handling code is necessary because IIRC it doesn't use `/` as the path separator.

Comment: I thought the whole cwd-per-volume made consistency between windows and other pretty much impossible.  Can you expand oh what you mean by "mishandle"?

Comment: @ysth, calling `splitdir` on a path instead of dirs returned by `splitpath`

Comment: @Chas. Owens, Perl is actively maintained for VMS.

Answer (score 4):

For usual file management inside Perl, No, File::Spec is not necessary and using forward slahes everywhere makes much less pain and works on Win32 anyways.

cpanminus is a good example used by lots of people and have been proved work great on win32 platform. it doesn't use File::Spec for most file path manipulation and just uses forward slashes - that was even suggested so by the experienced Perl-Win32 developers.

The only place I had to use File::Spec's catfile in cpanm, though, is where I extract file paths from a perl error message (`Can't locate File\Path.pm blah blah`) and create a file path to pass to the command line (i.e. cmd.exe).

Meanwhile File::Spec provides useful functions such as canonical and rel2abs - that's not "necessary" per se but really useful.

Comment: Forward slashes don't always work on Windows. I have plenty of test failures where the environment decided to build paths with backslashes, so making my own paths with forward slashes weren't the same strings I got back from whatever I was using. With File::Spec, I always got whatever that environment would make.

Comment: Right, making your own paths with forwarding slashes might not be the same with you got back from the environment - but that doesn't mean forward slashes "do not work". Forward slashes do work, even with combined with backslashes inside your perl code. There are exceptions like i described in the post, though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes absolutely.

<strike>Golden rule of programming, never hard code string literals.</strike>

Edit: One of the best ways to avoid porting issues is to avoid OS specific constants especially in the form of inline literals.

<strike>i.e</strike> e.g drive + ":/" + path + "/" + filename

<strike>It is bad practice yet</strike> We all commit these attrocities in the haste of the moment or because it doesn't matter for that piece of code. File::Spec is there for when a programmer is adhering to gospel programming.

In addition it provides the values of special and often used system directories e.g tmp or devnull which can vary from one distribution/OS to another.

If anything it could probably do with some other members added to it like user to point to the users home directory

Comment: What you claim is the golden rule of programming is completely wrong. The example (for which "e.g." and not "i.e." is the correct latin) of a harded coded string literal isn't even a string literal. In fact, if it was a hardcoded string literal, it probably wouldn't be buggy!

Comment: Example of perfectly good code with two hardcoded string literals: `open(my $fh, '<', $qfn) or die("open: $!");`

Comment: @ikegami Neither string is a particularly good example of a good hardcoded string.  You may want to change `'<'` to `'<:utf8'` at some later time; similarly, you may want to change the error messages (and should be using `autodie` anyway).  That said, yeah, I do that too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors, ikegami. It was late at night and I was tired. I have revised accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

makepp (makepp.sourceforge.net) has a makefile variable $/ which is either / or \ (on non-Cygwin Win).  The reason is that Win accepts / in filenames, but not in command names (where it starts an option).

Answer (score 0):

From http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html:

> catdir
>
> Concatenate two or more directory names to form a complete path ending with a directory. But remove the trailing slash from the resulting string, because it doesn't look good, isn't necessary and confuses OS/2. Of course, if this is the root directory, don't cut off the trailing slash :-)

So for example in this [example](https://github.com/tempire/app-dirserve/blob/master/dirserve) I wouldn't need the regex to remove the trailing slash if I would use `catdir`.